# Multiple multicolumns in one row in tables problem

Tags: tables, multicolumn

I have the following table:
[image: table with multiple multicolumns in the first row]

How do I get rid of the first multicolumn with no contents on the very left, in a way that the other multicolumns stay exactly like they are? Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htpb]
    \centering
    \begin{adjustbox}{max width =\textwidth}
    \begin{tabular}{|>{\bfseries}l|*{16}{l|}}
    \hline
         \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & % The multicolumn in question
         \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{1. Oktave}} & 
         \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{2. Oktave}} & 
         \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{3. Oktave}} & 
         \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{4. Oktave}} & 
         \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{5. Oktave}} & 
         \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{6. Oktave}} & 
         \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{7. Oktave}} & 
         \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{8. Oktave}} \\ \hline

         Ton & $n$ & Hertz & $n$ & Hertz & $n$ & Hertz & $n$ & Hertz &  $n$ & Hertz & $n$ & Hertz & $n$ & Hertz & $n$ & Hertz  \\ \hline
         $\boldsymbol{A}$ & 0 & 27,500 & 12 & 55,000 & 24 & 110,000 & 36 & 220,000 & 48 & 440,000 & 60 & 880,000 & 72 & 1760,000 & 84 & 3520,000 \\
         $\boldsymbol{A\sharp /B\flat}$ & 1 & 29,135 & 13 & 58,270 & 25 & 116,541 & 37 & 233,082 & 49 & 466,164 & 61 & 932,328 & 73 & 1864,655 & 85 & 3729,310 \\
         $\boldsymbol{B}$ & 2 & 30,868 & 14 & 61,735 & 26 & 123,471 & 38 & 246,942 & 50 & 493,883 & 62 & 987,767 & 74 & 1975,533 & 86 & 3951,066 \\
         $\boldsymbol{C}$ & 3 & 32,703 & 15 & 65,406 & 27 & 130,813 & 39 & 261,626 & 51 & 523,251 & 63 & 1046,502 & 75 & 2093,005 & 87 & 4186,009 \\
         $\boldsymbol{C\sharp/D\flat}$ & 4 & 34,648 & 16 & 69,296 & 28 & 138,591 & 40 & 277,183 & 52 & 554,365 & 64 & 1108,731 & 76 & 2217,461 &  &  \\
         $\boldsymbol{D}$ & 5 & 36,708 & 17 & 73,416 & 29 & 146,832 & 41 & 293,665 & 53 & 587,330 & 65 & 1174,659 & 77 & 2349,318 &  &  \\
         $\boldsymbol{D\sharp/E\flat}$ & 6 & 38,891 & 18 & 77,782 & 30 & 155,563 & 42 & 311,127 & 54 & 622,254 & 66 & 1244,508 & 78 & 2489,016 &  &  \\
         $\boldsymbol{E}$ & 7 & 41.203 & 19 & 82,407 & 31 & 164,814 & 43 & 329,628 & 55 & 659,255 & 67 & 1318,510 & 79 & 2637,021 &  &  \\
         $\boldsymbol{F}$ & 8 & 43,654 & 20 & 87,307 & 32 & 174,614 & 44 & 349,228 & 56 & 698,456 & 68 & 1396,913 & 80 & 2793,826 &  &  \\
         $\boldsymbol{F\sharp/G\flat}$ & 9 & 46,249 & 21 & 92,499 & 33 & 184,997 & 45 & 369,994 & 57 & 739,989 & 69 & 1479,978 & 81 & 2959,955 &  &  \\
         $\boldsymbol{G}$ & 10 & 48,999 & 22 & 97,999 & 34 & 195,998 & 46 & 391,995 & 58 & 783,991 & 70 & 1567,982 & 82 & 3135,964 &  &  \\
         $\boldsymbol{G\sharp/A\flat}$ & 11 & 51,913 & 23 & 103,826 & 35 & 207,652 & 47 & 415,305 & 59 & 830,609 & 71 & 1661,219 & 83 & 3322,438 &  &  \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{adjustbox}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are looking for the `\cline{<start column>-<end column>}`. In contrast to `\hline` `\cline` draws a horizontal line from column `<start column>` to `<end column>`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htpb]
    \centering
    \begin{adjustbox}{max width =\textwidth}
    \begin{tabular}{|>{\bfseries}l|*{16}{l|}}
        \cline{2-17}
         \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & % The multicolumn in question
         \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{1. Oktave}} & 
         \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{2. Oktave}} & 
         \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{3. Oktave}} & 
         \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{4. Oktave}} & 
         \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{5. Oktave}} & 
         \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{6. Oktave}} & 
         \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{7. Oktave}} & 
         \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{8. Oktave}} \\ \hline

         Ton & $n$ & Hertz & $n$ & Hertz & $n$ & Hertz & $n$ & Hertz &  $n$ & Hertz & $n$ & Hertz & $n$ & Hertz & $n$ & Hertz  \\ \hline
         $\boldsymbol{A}$ & 0 & 27,500 & 12 & 55,000 & 24 & 110,000 & 36 & 220,000 & 48 & 440,000 & 60 & 880,000 & 72 & 1760,000 & 84 & 3520,000 \\
         $\boldsymbol{A\sharp /B\flat}$ & 1 & 29,135 & 13 & 58,270 & 25 & 116,541 & 37 & 233,082 & 49 & 466,164 & 61 & 932,328 & 73 & 1864,655 & 85 & 3729,310 \\
         $\boldsymbol{B}$ & 2 & 30,868 & 14 & 61,735 & 26 & 123,471 & 38 & 246,942 & 50 & 493,883 & 62 & 987,767 & 74 & 1975,533 & 86 & 3951,066 \\
         $\boldsymbol{C}$ & 3 & 32,703 & 15 & 65,406 & 27 & 130,813 & 39 & 261,626 & 51 & 523,251 & 63 & 1046,502 & 75 & 2093,005 & 87 & 4186,009 \\
         $\boldsymbol{C\sharp/D\flat}$ & 4 & 34,648 & 16 & 69,296 & 28 & 138,591 & 40 & 277,183 & 52 & 554,365 & 64 & 1108,731 & 76 & 2217,461 &  &  \\
         $\boldsymbol{D}$ & 5 & 36,708 & 17 & 73,416 & 29 & 146,832 & 41 & 293,665 & 53 & 587,330 & 65 & 1174,659 & 77 & 2349,318 &  &  \\
         $\boldsymbol{D\sharp/E\flat}$ & 6 & 38,891 & 18 & 77,782 & 30 & 155,563 & 42 & 311,127 & 54 & 622,254 & 66 & 1244,508 & 78 & 2489,016 &  &  \\
         $\boldsymbol{E}$ & 7 & 41.203 & 19 & 82,407 & 31 & 164,814 & 43 & 329,628 & 55 & 659,255 & 67 & 1318,510 & 79 & 2637,021 &  &  \\
         $\boldsymbol{F}$ & 8 & 43,654 & 20 & 87,307 & 32 & 174,614 & 44 & 349,228 & 56 & 698,456 & 68 & 1396,913 & 80 & 2793,826 &  &  \\
         $\boldsymbol{F\sharp/G\flat}$ & 9 & 46,249 & 21 & 92,499 & 33 & 184,997 & 45 & 369,994 & 57 & 739,989 & 69 & 1479,978 & 81 & 2959,955 &  &  \\
         $\boldsymbol{G}$ & 10 & 48,999 & 22 & 97,999 & 34 & 195,998 & 46 & 391,995 & 58 & 783,991 & 70 & 1567,982 & 82 & 3135,964 &  &  \\
         $\boldsymbol{G\sharp/A\flat}$ & 11 & 51,913 & 23 & 103,826 & 35 & 207,652 & 47 & 415,305 & 59 & 830,609 & 71 & 1661,219 & 83 & 3322,438 &  &  \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{adjustbox}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Improvements

To make your table look more appealing you should consider to add features provided by the `booktabs` and `cellspace` package.

#### Cellspace

With `cellspace` you can customize the vertical spacing of the cells. The desired spacing between the content and the top or the bottom of the cell is determined by `\cellspacetoplimit` and `\cellspacebottomlimit`.

The changes take only effect if the column types are prepended by a special modifier. By default the modifier is the single character `S`

In your case `S` conflicts with the `S`-column type that is introduced by `siunitx`. To resolve the conflict between `siunitx` and `cellspace` you can choose a different modifier. To change the modifier from `S` to `O` for example you have to invoke `\usepackage[column=O]{cellspace}`.

In your case you not only have to modify the column types in the table preamble but also in the `\multicolumn` command.

The following example illustrates that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[column=O]{cellspace}

\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{0.5em}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{0.5em}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htpb]
    \centering
    \begin{adjustbox}{max width =\textwidth}
        \begin{tabular}{|>{\bfseries}O{l}|*{16}{O{l}|}}
            \cline{2-17}
            \multicolumn{1}{O{c}|}{} & % The multicolumn in question
            \multicolumn{2}{O{c}|}{\textbf{1. Oktave}} & 
            \multicolumn{2}{O{c}|}{\textbf{2. Oktave}} & 
            \multicolumn{2}{O{c}|}{\textbf{3. Oktave}} & 
            \multicolumn{2}{O{c}|}{\textbf{4. Oktave}} & 
            \multicolumn{2}{O{c}|}{\textbf{5. Oktave}} & 
            \multicolumn{2}{O{c}|}{\textbf{6. Oktave}} & 
            \multicolumn{2}{O{c}|}{\textbf{7. Oktave}} & 
            \multicolumn{2}{O{c}|}{\textbf{8. Oktave}} \\ \hline

            Ton & $n$ & Hertz & $n$ & Hertz & $n$ & Hertz & $n$ & Hertz &  $n$ & Hertz & $n$ & Hertz & $n$ & Hertz & $n$ & Hertz  \\ \hline
            $\boldsymbol{A}$ & 0 & 27,500 & 12 & 55,000 & 24 & 110,000 & 36 & 220,000 & 48 & 440,000 & 60 & 880,000 & 72 & 1760,000 & 84 & 3520,000 \\
            $\boldsymbol{A\sharp /B\flat}$ & 1 & 29,135 & 13 & 58,270 & 25 & 116,541 & 37 & 233,082 & 49 & 466,164 & 61 & 932,328 & 73 & 1864,655 & 85 & 3729,310 \\
            $\boldsymbol{B}$ & 2 & 30,868 & 14 & 61,735 & 26 & 123,471 & 38 & 246,942 & 50 & 493,883 & 62 & 987,767 & 74 & 1975,533 & 86 & 3951,066 \\
            $\boldsymbol{C}$ & 3 & 32,703 & 15 & 65,406 & 27 & 130,813 & 39 & 261,626 & 51 & 523,251 & 63 & 1046,502 & 75 & 2093,005 & 87 & 4186,009 \\
            $\boldsymbol{C\sharp/D\flat}$ & 4 & 34,648 & 16 & 69,296 & 28 & 138,591 & 40 & 277,183 & 52 & 554,365 & 64 & 1108,731 & 76 & 2217,461 &  &  \\
            $\boldsymbol{D}$ & 5 & 36,708 & 17 & 73,416 & 29 & 146,832 & 41 & 293,665 & 53 & 587,330 & 65 & 1174,659 & 77 & 2349,318 &  &  \\
            $\boldsymbol{D\sharp/E\flat}$ & 6 & 38,891 & 18 & 77,782 & 30 & 155,563 & 42 & 311,127 & 54 & 622,254 & 66 & 1244,508 & 78 & 2489,016 &  &  \\
            $\boldsymbol{E}$ & 7 & 41.203 & 19 & 82,407 & 31 & 164,814 & 43 & 329,628 & 55 & 659,255 & 67 & 1318,510 & 79 & 2637,021 &  &  \\
            $\boldsymbol{F}$ & 8 & 43,654 & 20 & 87,307 & 32 & 174,614 & 44 & 349,228 & 56 & 698,456 & 68 & 1396,913 & 80 & 2793,826 &  &  \\
            $\boldsymbol{F\sharp/G\flat}$ & 9 & 46,249 & 21 & 92,499 & 33 & 184,997 & 45 & 369,994 & 57 & 739,989 & 69 & 1479,978 & 81 & 2959,955 &  &  \\
            $\boldsymbol{G}$ & 10 & 48,999 & 22 & 97,999 & 34 & 195,998 & 46 & 391,995 & 58 & 783,991 & 70 & 1567,982 & 82 & 3135,964 &  &  \\
            $\boldsymbol{G\sharp/A\flat}$ & 11 & 51,913 & 23 & 103,826 & 35 & 207,652 & 47 & 415,305 & 59 & 830,609 & 71 & 1661,219 & 83 & 3322,438 &  &  \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{adjustbox}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Cellspace and Booktabs

To make the layout even more appealing you can also follow the guidelines for the `booktabs` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[column=O]{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{0.5em}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{0.5em}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htpb]
    \centering
    \begin{adjustbox}{max width =\textwidth}
    \begin{tabular}{>{\bfseries}O{l}*{16}{O{l}}}
         \toprule
         \multicolumn{1}{O{c}}{} & % The multicolumn in question
         \multicolumn{2}{O{c}}{\textbf{1. Oktave}} & 
         \multicolumn{2}{O{c}}{\textbf{2. Oktave}} & 
         \multicolumn{2}{O{c}}{\textbf{3. Oktave}} & 
         \multicolumn{2}{O{c}}{\textbf{4. Oktave}} & 
         \multicolumn{2}{O{c}}{\textbf{5. Oktave}} & 
         \multicolumn{2}{O{c}}{\textbf{6. Oktave}} & 
         \multicolumn{2}{O{c}}{\textbf{7. Oktave}} & 
         \multicolumn{2}{O{c}}{\textbf{8. Oktave}} \\ 
         \cmidrule(r{0.4em}){2-3}
         \cmidrule(l{0.4em}r{0.4em}){4-5}
         \cmidrule(l{0.4em}r{0.4em}){6-7}
         \cmidrule(l{0.4em}r{0.4em}){8-9}
         \cmidrule(l{0.4em}r{0.4em}){10-11}
         \cmidrule(l{0.4em}r{0.4em}){12-13}
         \cmidrule(l{0.4em}r{0.4em}){14-15}
         \cmidrule(l{0.4em}){16-17}

         Ton & $n$ & Hertz & $n$ & Hertz & $n$ & Hertz & $n$ & Hertz &  $n$ & Hertz & $n$ & Hertz & $n$ & Hertz & $n$ & Hertz  \\ \midrule 
         $\boldsymbol{A}$ & 0 & 27,500 & 12 & 55,000 & 24 & 110,000 & 36 & 220,000 & 48 & 440,000 & 60 & 880,000 & 72 & 1760,000 & 84 & 3520,000 \\
         $\boldsymbol{A\sharp /B\flat}$ & 1 & 29,135 & 13 & 58,270 & 25 & 116,541 & 37 & 233,082 & 49 & 466,164 & 61 & 932,328 & 73 & 1864,655 & 85 & 3729,310 \\
         $\boldsymbol{B}$ & 2 & 30,868 & 14 & 61,735 & 26 & 123,471 & 38 & 246,942 & 50 & 493,883 & 62 & 987,767 & 74 & 1975,533 & 86 & 3951,066 \\
         $\boldsymbol{C}$ & 3 & 32,703 & 15 & 65,406 & 27 & 130,813 & 39 & 261,626 & 51 & 523,251 & 63 & 1046,502 & 75 & 2093,005 & 87 & 4186,009 \\
         $\boldsymbol{C\sharp/D\flat}$ & 4 & 34,648 & 16 & 69,296 & 28 & 138,591 & 40 & 277,183 & 52 & 554,365 & 64 & 1108,731 & 76 & 2217,461 &  &  \\
         $\boldsymbol{D}$ & 5 & 36,708 & 17 & 73,416 & 29 & 146,832 & 41 & 293,665 & 53 & 587,330 & 65 & 1174,659 & 77 & 2349,318 &  &  \\
         $\boldsymbol{D\sharp/E\flat}$ & 6 & 38,891 & 18 & 77,782 & 30 & 155,563 & 42 & 311,127 & 54 & 622,254 & 66 & 1244,508 & 78 & 2489,016 &  &  \\
         $\boldsymbol{E}$ & 7 & 41.203 & 19 & 82,407 & 31 & 164,814 & 43 & 329,628 & 55 & 659,255 & 67 & 1318,510 & 79 & 2637,021 &  &  \\
         $\boldsymbol{F}$ & 8 & 43,654 & 20 & 87,307 & 32 & 174,614 & 44 & 349,228 & 56 & 698,456 & 68 & 1396,913 & 80 & 2793,826 &  &  \\
         $\boldsymbol{F\sharp/G\flat}$ & 9 & 46,249 & 21 & 92,499 & 33 & 184,997 & 45 & 369,994 & 57 & 739,989 & 69 & 1479,978 & 81 & 2959,955 &  &  \\
         $\boldsymbol{G}$ & 10 & 48,999 & 22 & 97,999 & 34 & 195,998 & 46 & 391,995 & 58 & 783,991 & 70 & 1567,982 & 82 & 3135,964 &  &  \\
         $\boldsymbol{G\sharp/A\flat}$ & 11 & 51,913 & 23 & 103,826 & 35 & 207,652 & 47 & 415,305 & 59 & 830,609 & 71 & 1661,219 & 83 & 3322,438 &  &  \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \end{adjustbox}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Could you briefly explain how your improvement works? I can't disassemble what commands are responsible for what really. I really enjoy that there is more space between the single rows but if I wanted to keep the rest like it was, I'm kind of lost.

Comment: @LinusDieLinse: I improved my answer with a more detailed description.